# Adding labels to pie chart in CorePlot: no idea how

Tags: ios, graph, customization, core-plot, label

I am using CorePlot for iOS and I have fond this graph example but I am unable to do the same on my graph.

[image]

Would you be able to suggest me what code to add to my graph in order to have labels within the triangle? The code I tried is the following:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumber * dataForItem = [self.dataForChart objectAtIndex:index];

    if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPTPieChart class]]){
        return  [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataForItem]];
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

However the result I get has labels that are not in the triangle:

[image]

---

I implemented the dataLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom legend entry labels in the "Simple Pie Chart" demo are provided by the `-attributedLegendTitleForPieChart:recordIndex:` datasource method. If you don't need attributed text in the label, you can use the `-legendTitleForPieChart:recordIndex:` method instead.

Comment: could you please add in your answer which method I need to implement in order to add the number on the slice? E.g. "99" in top yellow slice, "28" in purple bottom slice.. etc..

Comment: Those are "data labels". Set the `labelTextStyle` and `labelFormatter` to display them with the desired appearance.

Comment: I tried to do it but they come out in a weird position.. would you be able to be a bit more specific on how I can get them in the same style as in the picture above? What is the style I need to choose?

Comment: would you be please able to have a look at this question of mine too? Thanks for answering the previous ones! I am trying to finish something today using CorePlot and all this help is immensely appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224530/coreplot-unable-to-change-pie-chart-position-displacement